# Image vertical centering error - has more space above than below

Tags: html, css

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6aYK/3/) demonstrate problem with centering image inside the anchor (insidde the div). It's very strange for me - why first image has more space above than below. Could somebody help me to fix this?

[image]

HTML code:

```
<div id="parent">
    <ul class="other-images">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.abc.net.au/radionational/image/4220698-3x2-700x467.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/malopes/malopes0901/malopes090100089/4185805-beatiful-spring-landscape-with-grass-and-sky--portrait-orientation.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://resources2.news.com.au/images/2012/09/09/1226468/512770-images.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#parent{
    background: gray;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.other-images{
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 -2%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.other-images > li:nth-of-type(8n+1) {
    clear: both;
}

.other-images > li:nth-of-type(n) {
    clear: none;
}

.other-images > li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2% 4%;
    width: 9%;
}

.other-images > li > a {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for alligning vertical. One of that is the one that you applied, making a with a line-height and giving to your image vertical-align:middle.
A second method would be to make your anchor with display:table and image has a display:table-cell with vertical-align middle.

More usefull informations can be find [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/)